# RESTful Java Webservice in iPhone

Tags: java, iphone, rest

I'm gonna need to implement some Java webservices, is there any RESTful Java API which works well in iPhone?

Thanks

Comment: Is the iPhone going to be running the Java code?  I didn't think that was possible.  Or is the Java code exposing a service on a server somewhere and the iPhone is just consuming that service?  If it's RESTful, then it really shouldn't matter from the perspective of the client.  That's kind of the point, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a big misunderstanding of how this will work.

A restful webservice sits on a server and the iphone will just send a http request to it, the fact of the request is coming from an iphone bears no difference to the setup.

Heres a good link to get started writing webservices in general.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no Java on iPhone.

But if you are looking for an API that comunicate with REST webservices, you can use `ASIHTTPRequest`

Answer (score 0):

This will help you more [Tutorial: Fetch and parse JSON](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-fetch-and-parse-json/)